# Unable to open .vhdx file in Hyper-V, after using Disk2vhd

Tags: windows, hyper-v, vhdx

I have a computer where for about a year I have been using boot menu to choose between Windows 7 Pro and Windows 10 Pro as I needed. However seems like after Windows 10 update that menu stopped working. I can now only boot to Windows 10. I tried to run Windows 7 directly but it wouldn't work either, tried to repair but it said that the version is different, I probably long time ago used some more rare version of Windows as all Windows 7 images I tried would not work.

I used Disk2vhd tool to convert hard drive with Windows 7 to virtual vhdx file. But it will not open in Hyper-V.

[error in hyper-v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uPrv.png)

I started searching and some suggest to mount the EFI System partition but in command prompt I don't see it in the list. So I am unable to mount it. Any advice on how to find out its volume name and mount it?

[list of partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNTSN.png)

Also there was a suggestion to use the hyper-v wizard to do the conversion to virtual system but even though I have Windows 10 Pro my wizard looks different.

[wizard difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TePAx.png)

Would appreciate any information on getting that vhd to run. I can access all files but there is a database program that I need access to so I need to login to actual windows system. Thanks!

PS: Error when trying to repair. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnkbe.png)

Comment: If Windows 7 doesn't boot from the physical disk, logic says that it also wouldn't boot from the virtual image of the disk, if the image was true enough. If you don't have an image backup of this disk, it's likely too badly damaged to use.

Comment: harrymc: While it is possible that it will not boot in virtual system either, I'd like to at least try it, but for it to have sufficient circumstances to boot the EFI System partition needs to be in place in the vhdx file.

Comment: Try Startup Repair from a Windows 7 installation ISO on the VM.

Comment: I did but as mentioned I don't have the correct ISO, I tried both 32 and 64 bit versions, but the version I have installed may be more rare one, like refurbished computer version or something like that.

Comment: First, the ISO version shouldn't matter to Startup repair. Second, I don't think such a version exists, the reason must be different.

Comment: I added screenshot of the error to post please look at it.

Comment: You might be encountering mismatch of UEFI/BIOS/GPT/MBR/32-64 bit. See for example [comment #23](https://www.sevenforums.com/backup-restore/415135-system-repair-disk-not-compatible-version-windows-post3393639.html#post3393639) after verifying your existing setup.

Comment: I need to load it in Hyper-V but the vhdx does not have the EFI system partition. I need to include it.